# why is nth-of-type not being recognized by sublime text?

Tags: css

The nth-of-type just appears to be in white as opposed to other elements. Sublime text doesn't seem to recognize it.

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to the question. You have an extra space between the `:` and the `nth` Use `:nth-child` instead of `: nth-child` or `:nth-of-type` instead of  `: nth-of-type` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have given extra space in this `: nth-of-type` try using this it may help you : `:nth-of-type`

Comment: if then also that not works you can upload your code at jsbin

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter.

This bothered me a lot when I was answering a specific question in a course. However, Sublime is just a text editor, it's your browser that reads the css and executes it.

As for *why*? I don't know. It confused me at first too.